# Why do I get clicks when I load, but not when I click?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, onclick

I'm stumped by odd behavior I'm getting with my JavaScript/d3 code. I [have elements](http://www.raxacoricofallapatorius.com/test/scattertest.html) that I've assigned `onclick` handlers to using d3 with `.on("click", ...` but these elements behave as if they've been clicked only when my page loads, and not when I click on them.

I suspect I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, but can't figure out what it is. How do I get the `onclick` handlers to run when I click on, but not when my page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you don't bind the functions as event handlers, you call the functions and use their return values as event handlers.

You can use function expressions to create function references that you can bind as event handlers. Inside the function expressions you use the function calls that you have now:

```
d3.select("#distancefig").on("click", function(){
  d3.event.preventDefault();
  updatePlot('distancefig', false));
});
d3.select("#speedfig").on("click", function(){
  d3.event.preventDefault();
  updatePlot('speedfig', false));
}),
```

Comment: That solves the problem of "clicking" on load, but my figure doesn't change when I (really) click. (Linked page updated to include this answer.)

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: I'm not sure what's supposed to happen, but I see that the page requests data from the server whenever you click the links, so the events really work.

Comment: Hmm, odd. The graph should update to show different data. If I execute the `updatePlot` function explicitly it does that, but not when I click.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Perhaps it's the link that is interfering with the result. You should stop the links from being activated. I added that to the code above.

Comment: I think this is [a distinct question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24307921/656912).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: That didn't solve it? Then there is some other difference than the code being run in an event. You should still use `preventDefault` though.

Comment: When I use `preventDefault`, clicking does nothing. Without it the clicks now work fine (answer accepted), [but it doesn't update the axes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24307921/656912), though it does everything else that it should.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Sorry, I was thinking jQuery, as the event binding is so similar. I adjusted the code for d3.

Answer (score 2):

Without any knowledge of D3, I'm guessing it's because you're doing this

```
d3.select("#distancefig").on("click", updatePlot('distancefig', false));
```

Rather then this

```
d3.select("#distancefig").on("click", function() {
  updatePlot('distancefig', false)
});
```

You are doing a function call when you intend to supply a function **to be** called.